# An error with Haskell classes I fall all the time and can't understand

Tags: haskell, class, type-systems

there's an error I come across all the time but can't understand how to make it right. An example of code that gives me this error is:

```
class Someclass a where
    somefunc :: (Num b) => b -> a -> a

data Sometype = Somecons Int

instance Someclass Sometype where
    somefunc x (Somecons y) = Somecons (x+y)
```

The error message is:

> Couldn't match expected type 'b' against inferred type 'Int'
>   'b' is a rigid type variable bound by
>   the type signature for 'somefunc' at error.hs:3:21
>   In the second argument of '(+)', namely 'y'
>   In the first argument of 'Somecons', namely '(x + y)'
>   In the expression: Somecons (x + y)

I understand that the error message is trying to tell me that I used a name of type Int where he was expecting something with type (Num b) => b. What I can't understand is that Int fits in (Num b)=>b. Shouldn't the compiler understand what I'm telling him (that for this specific instance b should be an integer? How can I make this fit?

Coment:
Of course in this specific example I could have made somefunc with type signature:

```
somefunc :: a -> a-> a
```

but supose I wanted something like:

```
data Newtype = Newcons (Int, Int) 

instance Someclass Newtype where
    somefunc x (Newtype (y,z) ) = Newtype (y+x, z)
```

Things like that recurrently happens when I'm trying to do something in haskell.

Comment: huh... I guess you mean `data ...` instead of `Data...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can make the point clearer when thinking of the generics notation using [universal quantification](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types).

```
somefunc :: (Num b) => b -> a -> a
```

therefore means nothing but

```
somefunc :: forall a b . Num b => b -> a -> a
```

This means your class function must be defined for **any** numeric `b`.

The code

```
Data Sometype = Somecons Int

instance Someclass Sometype where
    somefunc x (Somecons y) = Somecons (x+y)
```

forces `b` to have **one** concrete type - `Int`, which doesn't conform with the requirement to work for any numeric type.

You might want to have something like this

```
class Num b => SomeClass a b where
    somefunc :: b -> a -> a

instance Someclass Somecons Int where
    -- ...
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem can be seen in the signature of the `+` operator:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Because of this, when you use `+` in `somefunc` with an `Int`, it forces b to be an `Int`, and therefore `somefunc` becomes:

```
somefunc :: Int -> Sometype -> Sometype
```

To implement the `Someclass` class, `somefunc` is expected to have this signature:

```
somefunc :: Num b => b -> Sometype -> Sometype
```

That is, it should work with any type that is an instance of `Num`. Your function *only* works with `Int`s.

Comment: doesn't somefunc become `:: Int -> Sometype -> Sometype` ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mix types, as `(+) :: a → a → a`

```
let x = 1.2::Double; y=2::Int in x + y
```

This will fail already.

Num is too general, if you specified that `x::Double` you could get it working by an explicit 'typecast' (`fromIntegral` )

```
instance Someclass Sometype where
    somefunc x (Somecons y) = Somecons (x + (fromIntegral y))
```

I think you want something like this

```
instance Someclass Sometype where

    somefunc :: Int → Sometype → Int
    somefunc x (Somecons y) = Somecons (x + y)
```

*btw, you need to type data instead of Data :-)*

Comment: The arrows and nice and all, but in Haskell there is no such thing. It's `->`.

Comment: I know, but it is common practice in the haskell literature to use the typographic symbols. Some haskell-editors even display these symbols the way I showcased.

Comment: I see. I prefer `->` because it is copy-pastable (not that I think anyone will copy-paste such contrived example code).

Answer (score 1):

To continue on Dario's example, what you seem to be asking for is:

```
class Someclass a where
    somefunc :: exists b . (Num b) => b -> a -> a
```

That is, instead of the "you pick a type, and my function will work" promise that `"forall b . Num b => b"` implies, you want the "I'll pick a type, so my function will work" promise of `"exists b . (Num b) => b"`, which Sr. Fernandes mentioned.
More importantly, you aren't showing how your constraint `(Num b) => b` helps your case.

The really interestingsituation would be: how should you class handle the following type:

```
data BMephType i o = BMT (i -> (o, BMephType i o))
instance Someclass (BMephType (Complex Double -> String) String) where
```

Most likely, your solution will involve a `Complex Double`. Somewhere. If it *only* involves a `Complex Double`, and no other `Num` types, then you're looking for an existential type, not a universal.